# Let $f:V \times W \to \mathbb F$ and $s:V \to W^*, r:W \to V^*$. Find $[s]^B_{C^*}, [r]^C_{B^*}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, duality-theorems, dual-spaces, bilinear-form

> Let $f:V \times W \to \mathbb F$ bilinear map and $s:V \to W^*, r:W \to V^*$ linear transformations s.t: $s(v)(w) = f(v,w)$ and $r(w)(v) = f(v,w), \forall v \in V$ and $\forall w \in W$. Let $B$ an ordered basis of $V$ and $C$ an ordered basis of $W$. Let $A$ be the transformation matrix of $f$ in the bases $B,C$ whilst $B^*,C^*$ are the dual bases for $V^*,W^*$ respectively. **Find: $[s]^B_{C^*}, [r]^C_{B^*}$**

So we haven't really seen dual spaces in Linear Algebra #1 and so this question really got me confused.

Basically I know that $V^*$ for example is $Hom(V,\mathbb F)$ and given some basis $B$ of $V$ we have $B^*$ a basis for $V^*$ where $b_i \in B^*$ is the linear functional $\phi_i$ which satsfies:

$\phi_i =
\begin{cases}
1 & i = j \\[2ex]
0 & i \neq j
\end{cases}$

So past this I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a *matrix* means to find all its *entries*.

In general, the matrix $M$ of a linear transformation $\varphi:X\to Y$ in the bases $\{x_i\},\{y_j\}$ of $X,Y$, respectively, is defined by the following equations on its entries $M_{ij}$: $$\varphi(x_i)=\sum_j M_{ij}y_j.$$
I'd suggest you note *the types* of objects on both sides - we have an equality of *what*? Answer: of vectors in $Y$.

In your case, carefully instantiate all variables with the specific ones in the problem:

- $\varphi$ is $s$
- $X$ is $V$, and $Y$ is $W^*$
- the basis vectors $x_i$ are $b_i$, and the basis vectors $y_j$ are $c^*_j$
  I denoted here by $\{c^*_j\}$ the basis of $W^*$ which is dual to the basis $\{c_i\}$ of $W$. As you noted in your question, we know that $c_i^*(c_i)=1$ and if $i\neq j,c_j^*(c_i)=0$.
- $M$ is $[s]^B_{C^*}$

and compute the same equation:

$$s(b_i)=\sum_j \left([s]^B_{C^*}\right)_{ij}c^*_j$$

Again, what do we equate here? Answer: elements of $W^*$. How do we get hold of the matrix entries $\left([s]^B_{C^*}\right)_{ij}$? By getting rid of the (co)vectors (functionals) $c^*_j$'s. How do we get rid of them?

Well, it's in their nature to *eat vectors* (they are functions from $\text{Hom}(W,\mathbb R)$, that is $c_j^*:W\to\mathbb R$, after all), and as you said, you know how the dual basis acts on (eats) the basis it is dual of - $c_i^*(c_i)=1$ and if $i\neq j, c_j^*(c_i)=0.$

Therefore it makes sense to *act on both sides* with $c_k$ (we have to use a new index so that it does not clash with the $i$ and $j$ we already use):

$$
\begin{align*}
s(b_{i})(c_{k}) &=\left(\sum_{j}\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ij}c_{j}^{*}\right)(c_{k})\\
 &=\sum_{j}\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ij}c_{j}^{*}(c_{k})
\end{align*}$$

Ask yourself again, what type of objects are we equating here?

Now if you apply your knowledge about the action $c_{j}^{*}(c_{k})$ in the cases where $j=k$ and $j\neq k$, you'll eliminate all terms in the sum but one and will find $\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ik}$.

Comment: First of all your answer is great and thank you for the exact details! Making sure I figured it out, assuming $B=\{b_1,...b_n\}$ and $C=\{c_1,...c_m\}$ we have:

$[s]^B_{C^*} \in M(\mathbb F)_{n \times m}$:
 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: and:

$[r]^C_{B^*} \in M(\mathbb F)_{m \times n}$:
 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: Uhm not really. What did you get for $s(b_{i})(c_{k}) =\sum_{j}\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ij}c_{j}^{*}(c_{k})=$?

Comment: By the calculations I made it is $0$ for the case $i \neq k$ and $1$ for the case $i = k$ thus meaning we only have $1's$ on the main diagonal and since I don't know the dimensions of $V,W$ we have $[s]^B_{C^*} \in M(\mathbb F)_{n \times m}$ and $[r]^C_{B^*} \in M(\mathbb F)_{m \times n}$

Comment: This is only for $c_{j}^{*}(c_{k})$ (which is either 0 or 1, yes), but you seem to forget the $\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ij}$ part in the sum :) Then you'll get something else for $s(b_{i})(c_{k})$ (and it is neither 0 nor 1).

Comment: But $s(b_i) = \psi_i$ which is defined as $\psi_i:W \to \mathbb F$ s.t $\forall c_k \in C$ we have $\psi_i(c_k) \neq 0 \iff i = k$. Isn't the sum part "vanished" because we only have one $j=k$?

Comment: No! But I see where you're wrong now. The dual basis to $c_{k}$ is $c_{j}^{*}$, *not* $s(b_{i})=\psi_{i}$. Hence it *does not hold* that $\psi_{i}(c_{k})=1$ or 0. That is true only for the functionals $c_{k}^{*}$, which are different from $\psi_{i}=s(b_{i})$. The $s(b_i)$ is a random given covector, and the $b_i$'s are another set of random given vectors, and the two are not necessarily dual to each other. The duals are only the $c_j$'s to the $c_j^*$'s.

Comment: So if you apply the 0/1 rule to each term in the sum, you get: $$s(b_{i})(c_{k})=\sum_{j}\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ij}c_{j}^{*}(c_{k})=\sum_{j\neq k}\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ij}\cdot0+\sum_{j=k}\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ij}\cdot1=\left([s]_{C^{*}}^{B}\right)_{ik},$$ telling you exactly what the wanted matrix entries are.